# Common template deduction from reference and const reference

Tags: c++

I have wrote a simple range class to view into vector(collection) of bytes.

```
using byte_vector = std::vector<uint8_t>;

template<typename Iter>
struct byte_range {
    static_assert( sizeof( typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type )== 1);
    using type = byte_range<Iter>;
    Iter first;
    Iter last;
    Iter begin()const{ return first; }
    Iter end()const{return last;}
    byte_range()=default;
    byte_range(Iter f, Iter l): first{f}, last{l} {}
    byte_range(byte_vector&v)      :byte_range(v.begin(),v.end()){}
    byte_range(byte_vector const&v):byte_range(v.begin(),v.end()){}
};
template<typename C> byte_range(C&)       -> byte_range<typename C::iterator>;
template<typename C> byte_range(C const&) -> byte_range<typename C::const_iterator>;
```

It can deduce Iter type from vector passed to constructor. But I found the only way to handle both non-const and const. I wonder if there a way to write one template deduction line for both.

I wanna squash two last lines into one. But how?

[Test code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b4f4451672e931):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    byte_vector bv {1,2,3,4,5};
    byte_range bri(begin(bv),end(bv));
    byte_range brv(bv);
    cout<<"---"<<endl;
    for(auto&br:{bri,brv}){
        for(auto&b:br)
            cout<<hex<<int(b)<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    byte_vector const bvc = {6,7,8,9,0};
    byte_range brc = bvc;
    for(auto&b:brc)
        cout<<hex<<int(b)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically from my answer to your last question:

```
template<typename C> byte_range(C& c) -> byte_range<decltype(c.begin())>;
```

and the constructor can be a single template that works with both:

```
template<typename C>
byte_range(C& v)      : byte_range(v.begin(),v.end()) {}
```

If you let the template parameter of `byte_range` be the container type and not the iterator type, you can also get rid of the deduction guide.

This also allows you to use range-like types that don't declare their `iterator` type as member. (For more generality you might want to use `std::begin`/`std::end` and in C++20 just use `std::ranges`.)

If you intend your class to represent only continuous ranges of byte-like types, then you probably should use a pointer interface though. Have a look at C++20's [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), its interface and its implementations.

Also `static_assert( sizeof( typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type )== 1);` doesn't really test what you intend to test. For example all empty classes probably have `sizeof` equal to `1`. You probably want to test whether the type satisfies either of `std::byte` or `unsigned char` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for responses and advises, very cognitive.

Answer (score 1):

If template argument deduction works with reference, constness is preserved.

For example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&) {}

const vector<int> v;
foo(v); // T will be deduced as const vector<int>
```

so, your two deduction guides can be merged as:

```
template<typename C>
byte_range(C&) -> 
  byte_range< std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<C>,
  typename C::const_iterator,
  typename C::iterator> >;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/-ibtJo)